# const ints as Message IDs = Recompile Everything

Tags: c++

I'm hoping for confirmation of what I just told someone.
We have a large software project that is divided out into several libraries (.so). The message definitions are all in one library with a set of .h files for the declarations. The message ids are in the .h as const int (see below). One uses the id to subscribe/publish the message.

They had to go and renumber the message ids. They were hoping just to drop in the new library.

I said that they have to recompile all the source that uses the library.

Const objects are internal linkage by default, so the external code that uses the id is *not* linked to an object changed by the library, rather it is a simple integer that is now out of sync with the library.

I feel very sure that I am right about this.... Or am I all wet?

```
namespace AppsMessages
{

const DataClassID_t CommandReqId(120097);

class CommandRequestMessage { ... };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

A better design (at least in terms of mitigating maintenance nightmares like *this one*) would be to declare these ID objects `extern` in the header, and *define* them once in the library source. Then you'd just have had to drop in the new library.

Comment: I was also thinking that a hash to prevents collisions could have been used, thus (hopefully) obviating the need to ever renumber.

Comment: @John: Probably not what you want for constant IDs.